# Scale images to desktop size with no borders with Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I have a bunch of images that are desktop wallpapers, but different sizes. For my examples, I will use the resolution 1920x1080. How do I scale the images so that:

- For images smaller than my screen in width and height, the image is centered and then scaled up proportionally until the smaller of the two reaches 1920 or 1080
- For images smaller than my screen in width or height, the image is centered and then

  - If the image is portrait, the width will be scaled up to 1920 and the height will be scaled proportionally
  - If the image is landscape, the height will be scaled up to 1080 and the width will be scaled proportionally
- For images larger than my screen in width and height, the image is centered and then

  - If the image is portrait, the width will be scaled down to 1920 and the height will be scaled proportionally
  - If the image is landscape, the height will be scaled down to 1080 and the width will be scaled proportionally

I tried `mogrify -resize 1920x *.png`, `mogrify resize x1080 *.png`, and `mogrify resize 1920x1080 *.png`, but I get borders on at least 1 image with each of these commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I've figured out what to do. There's a new feature in ImageMagick 6.3.8-3 called the  Fill Area Flag. The command for what I'm looking for is:

```
mogrify -resize 1920x1080^ -gravity center *
```

This will center the image and resize it to the correct dimensions.